# How call code within class function from require_once?

Tags: php

If I create a class that uses a variable defined in another php file that is included via `require_once`, I get the following outcomes:

1. If `require_once` is at the top of the class's php file and the variable is used in `myclass->someFunction()` it will throw the error: `Undefined variable`
2. If `require_once` is inside `myclass->someFunction()` it work **once** and thereafter throw the error: `Undefined variable`

How do I properly handle this?

Example showing the problem:

**test.php**

```
<?php
    require_once( "holds_var.php" );

    class T
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->useVariable();
        }

        function useVariable()
        {
            echo $something;
        }
    }

    $t = new T();
?>
```

**holds_var.php**

```
<?php $something = "I am something"; ?>
```

EXAMPLE 2 (uses the same "holds_var.php" ):

**test.php**

```
<?php   
    class T
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            //This is ok
            $this->useVariable();

            //This throws an error
            $this->useVariable();
        }

        function useVariable()
        {
            require_once( "holds_var.php" );
            echo $something;
        }
    }

    $t = new T();
?>
```

Comment: First it's not a good practice to create a dependency between a class file and another file. If you really wish to do so, you might want to pass the variable to the object either through constructor function or the specific function that you want to use the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
function useVariable()
    {
        global $something;
        require_once( "holds_var.php" );
        echo $something;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `global` could help your case.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

holds_var.php

```
<?php
    $something = "I am something";
    global $something;
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php   
    require_once( "holds_var.php" );
    class T
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            //This is ok
            $this->useVariable();

            //This throws an error
            $this->useVariable();
        }

        function useVariable()
        {
            global $something;
            echo $something;
        }
    }

    $t = new T();
?>
```

How does the above code work out for you?